Parallel Mediation Model Diagram
I am building a parallel mediation model diagram but am not sure what one of the numbers signifies despite 30 minutes of Goolging.
The number in question is what's in the parenthesis for the c' path —highlighted in yellow in the attached example. What does 1.73 in this case signify?

The short answer? The direct effect of group membership on outcome. The A-D variables are mediators that represent indirect effects. I can tell you from experience conducting significance testing of the mediation effect is not fun. I actually did this exact model set up in grad school. Feel free to DM me if ya need assistance.
